# Fatal error with composer in a new installation of codeigniter 4

Tags: composer-php, codeigniter-4

I am trying to install CodeIgniter 4.3.1 on a shared Linus server using composer.

**Two different versions of composer are installed** (by the hosting company) on that server.

-bash-4.2$ **composer2** --version Composer version 2.0.12

-bash-4.2$ **composer** --version Composer version 1.10.21

The installation is done using compose2 without any problem
(`composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter myAppName`)

When I try to run the site I encounter the following message.

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Your Composer version is too old. Please update Composer (run composer self-update) to v2.0.14 or later and remove your vendor/ directory,
and run composer update. in /home/..../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php:377
Stack trace: #0 /home/..../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php(143):
CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadComposerNamespaces()
#1 /home/..../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php(125): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadComposerInfo()
#2 /home/.../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php(105): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->initialize()
#3 /home/..../public/index.php(38): require('/home/u86872913...')
#4 {main} thrown in /home/.../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php on line 377

I can't run `composer self-update' because I don't have read/write permissions to this area.

I tried to install (`composer install --working-dir=/home/..../vendor` ) in the ci4 vendor path, but the message remain.

Even if i run `php composer.phar --version` in that directory i get  **Composer version 2.5.3**.

I did not found where composer path is defined  in ci4 ( COMPOSER_PATH => /vendor/autoload.php   )
Or  how can i point ci4 to the correct installation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to run Composer on any shared server? Why not ask whoever maintains that server to update it for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, This is a big company and they are not willing to update, they claim because of legacy to other customers.And the reason for using composer installation that is recommended in any article of codeigniter4 installation. I can install manually and it is working(I tried that), but i like to do as recommended.Even if they upgrade composer steel the newest version will run with composer2 command and ci4 not know about that .

Comment: Finally, the way to bypass the problem is to downgrade the ci4 version to 4.1.9 by running  "composer require codeigniter4/framework:4.1.9"  .

Comment: @xShen Did you tried this ? (removing vendor) 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_430.html#composer-version

Comment: Thank  you , i did solved the problem but i don't know  how to close this question. the message was because i installed ci4 using the sever composer (2.0.12). Ci(V 4.3.1)   not like this and required newer composer version. End of story: i installed last ver of composer on my ci directory and use it like php composer.phar create-project-----  , now every thing  works 

Comment: Regurding your comment @b126 , Yes i did as in this line: " I can't run `composer self-update' because I don't have read/write permissions to this area(server instilation)".

Comment: You should go to the official CodeIgniter forum, they are super reactive

Comment: @b126   You are correct. I should. But as i wrote in previous comment problem solved.

Comment: I understand but downgrading won't solve the problem for very long ;)

Comment: Sorry @b126, I probably didn't explain myself properly,At the end , I installed the latest version of ci  ver 4.3.1  . The error message was ci complains on composer version in the server . So i installed in app folder the latest composer and use it from there . and now everything is working as expected with the latest version.♦ this topic is solved.no more answer needed.